# Nexus 3 - File Upload to hosted Maven Repository

Tags: curl, nexus, sonatype

I want to upload some files to a newly generated hosted Maven Repository on my **Nexus OSS 3** Instance.

I need to use **curl** (not maven or something else) for the upload.

I tried the following statement (Port is not necessary - I have a NginX as reverse Proxy)

```
curl -v -F r=releases -F hasPom=false -F e=jar -F g=com.my.group -F a=myArtifact -F v=1.0.0-RC1 -F p=jar --upload-file "myArtifact.jar" -u user:password123 http://myNexusInstance.com/repository/myRepository
```

This Command produces the following Error:

```
* Server auth using Basic with user 'user'
PUT /repository/myRepository HTTP/1.1
Host: myNexusInstance.com
Authorization: Basic xxxx=
User-Agent: curl/7.49.1
Accept: */*
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Expect: 100-continue
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
} [16380 bytes data]
HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid path for a Maven 2 repository
```

I tried googling around but did not find any Solution (Neither in the Nexus OSS 3.x Documentation nor in different Forums)

The Nexus Repository is setup with the following configuration values:

- Format: maven2
- Type: hosted
- Version policy: Release
- Layout policy: Strict
- Deployment policy: Allow redeploy (also tested "Disable redeploy")

What is wrong here?

Comment: As "workaround" I used "mvn deploy:deploy-file" which requires an existing maven installation but works. Would be fine to have a tool-independent Upload mechanism.

Comment: If that works, I would use something like Charles to see what endpoint it is using. From there you can likely easily retool curl to work.

Answer (score 12):

You can't use the service urls in Nexus Repository 3. To do something like you are trying to do, try this:

`curl -v -u admin:admin123 --upload-file myArtifact.jar http://nexusURL:nexusPORT/repository/myRepository/com/my/group/myArtifact/1.0.0-RC1/myArtifact-1.0.0-RC1.jar`

That SHOULD do the trick?

For some good reading, you can check out the following link that explains a remote repository layout (and hopefully helps explain why what I suggested to do works):

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Remote+repository+layout#Remoterepositorylayout-Repositoryartifactlayout

Comment: No, same Error-Message (invalid path for a Maven 2 repository).
I think the --upload-file Call only works on raw repositories

Comment: Do you use a context path with Nexus Repository or is it just /?

Comment: "Doesn't work either" is not enough information. How something doesn't work is required...please be more specific.

Comment: One other thing you might try is to set the repository layout policy to permissive in the Repo Admin, although I'm not sure why the call isn't working for you. Other ideas are to try the curl command directly against Nexus Repository without the reverse proxy in the middle, to ensure there isn't something wild going on there.

Comment: @Peter Lynch: It throws the same exception than the previous call (400 Invalid path for a Maven 2 repository) - The difference between call 1 and call 2 was in the path (original Post contained "release(s)" in the path)

Comment: The following worked for me with disable redeploy, release, and strict layout policy for nexus 3.2.1;  `curl -v --user username:password --upload-file /path/sample.war  http://nexus.company.com:8081/nexus/repository/myrepo/com/company/sample-app/1.0.1/sample-app-1.0.1.war`  Note, we have the app context set to /nexus, which isn't there by default in nexus three.

Comment: this link helped me the most to understand the url params in the upload.

Comment: Using the curl command, you must be aware that the file name **(myArtifact-1.0.0-RC1)** must be equal to the concatenation of the final part of the repository path **(myArtifact/1.0.0-RC1)**.

`curl -v -u admin:admin123 --upload-file myArtifact.jar http://nexusURL:nexusPORT/repository/myRepository/com/my/group/myArtifact/1.0.0-RC1/myArtifact-1.0.0-RC1.jar`